# Save Json Data Using Go language

Tags: go

I am trying to Parse Json & save Student Pecentage to a csv file using GO language .

With below code i am able to print and save Rollno. and marks in a csv successfully .

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func PageRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Default page number is 1
    if len(r.URL.Path) <= 1 {
        r.URL.Path = "/1"
    }

    // Page number is not negative or 0
    page.Abs(page)
    if page.Cmp(one) == -1 {
        page.SetInt64(1)
    }

    // Page header
    fmt.Fprintf(w, PageHeader, pages, previous, next)

    // Save in csv
    csvfile, err := os.OpenFile("marks.csv", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(csvfile)
    defer writer.Flush()

    // Marks for UID
    UID, length := compute(start)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        key := UID[i]

        fmt.Fprintf(w, key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno) 



        records := [][]string{{key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno}}

        for _, record := range records {
            err := writer.Write(record)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                return
            }
        }


    }

    // Page Footer
    fmt.Fprintf(w, PageFooter, previous, next)
}
```

This is what I am doing

1. Visitor visits studentmarks.com/page=1 RollNo. & Marks for 10 students are displayed and it is also saved in a CSV [Working Perfectly with above code]
2. It Makes a request to studentpercentagejson.com/Roll1,Roll2,Roll3 (all RollNo. that we got in step1)
   The Json response would be like

   ```
   [{"name":"James","Percentage":96.5,"RollNo":101}, 
   {"name":"William","Percentage":36.0,"RollNo":102}, 
   {"name":"Jacob","Percentage":63.0,"RollNo":103}, 
   {"name":"Wilson","Percentage":69.3,"RollNo":104}, 
   {"name":"Kurtson","Percentage":16.9,"RollNo":105}, 
   {"name":"Tom","Percentage":86.3,"RollNo":106}]
   ```
3. Extract Name & Percentage fields & save in a csv .

progress so far -

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type object []struct {
    Name       string  `json:"name"`
    Percentage float64 `json:"Percentage"`
    RollNo     int     `json:"RollNo"`
}

func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", PageRequest)
    res, err := http.Get("https://studentpercentagejson.com/key.rollno")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()


    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("whoops:", err)
    }
log.Println("Listening")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

How can I print and save Percentage extracted from the JSON Response using go language?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're doing using server APIs. But I answer how to decode JSON from http response.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type object []struct {
}

type ObjectsAPIResponse struct {
    Allmarks []object
}

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("https://studentpercentagejson.com/key.rollno")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    var s ObjectsAPIResponse
    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("whoops:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s.Allmarks)
}
```

### Collect RollNo(s)

```
var rollNos []string
for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
    key := UID[i]

    fmt.Fprintf(w, key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno) 

    records := [][]string{{key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno}}

    rollNos = append(rollNos, key.rollno)

    for _, record := range records {
        err := writer.Write(record)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
uri := "http://studentpercentagejson.com/" + strings.Join(rollNos, ",")
res, err := http.Get(uri)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

var s ObjectsAPIResponse
err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(s.Allmarks[0].Name)
fmt.Println(s.Allmarks[0].Percentage)
fmt.Println(s.Allmarks[0].RollNo)
```

Comment: It should make a request to studentpercentagejson.com/Roll1,Roll2,Roll3 (all RollNo. that we got in step1), how can we achieve this?

Comment: I don't know how the server works. If the server accept multiple parameters which can pass all of RollNo(s), just add request parameters. If not, you should make loop to get response, and append to the list.

Comment: the server can accept multiple rollno,(upto 200) separated by ","  so we can use the roll no. we got in step#1 and can extract the percentage in a csv

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing where to go next step. What is you problem?

Comment: I am unable to find a way on how to seperate Rollno. we got in step#1 (key.rollno) with "," and use it as studentpercentagejson.com/Roll1,Roll2,Roll3,...

Comment: Do you mean how to make request URI from objects? https://play.golang.org/p/LFl9q4MQpS

Comment: In the code  i have records := [][]string{{key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno}}, which stores key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno . Now,for step#2 we need key.rollno and use that in studentpercentagejson.com/Roll1,Roll2,Roll3 ...

Comment: then, I guess it should be `for _, v := range arr { rollnos = append(rollnos, v[2]) }`

Comment: I think you are confusing, i have edited the question, please check "This is what I am doing" and then read the codes

Comment: What do you mean `print`? write to http response? or print into stdout?

Comment: if you mean " fmt.Fprintf(w, key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno) " then its writing to http response,its working perfectly, and key.rollno has the values we need in step#2

Comment: In my code above, you can see `s.Allmarks[N].RollNo` is that.

Comment: why we need `s.Allmarks[N].RollNo` ? we need to use the values for  `key.rollno` in my code in the request `studentpercentagejson.com/Roll1,Roll2,Roll3`

Comment: If you have already `[][]string{{key.fname, key.marks, key.rollno}}` , should be v[N][2] see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872060/save-json-data-using-go-language/44872645?noredirect=1#comment76724409_44872645) above.

Comment: I can't do correctly. because I still not understand what you want to do.

Comment: ok,now step#3 Extract Name & Percentage fields from JSON response & save in a csv

Comment: In step#3 how can we extract name and percentage field from JSON response and save in csv?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. I guess that you can do it in your-self. There are enough code to do, I think.

Comment: yup,everything is working perfectly,after decoding the JSON body we need to extract the "percentage" and save it in a csv,the example JSON response is in my question